# Many projects in solution on slow dev environment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, virtual-machine, projects-and-solutions

Currently we have a VS2010 solution with 40+ projects and all the team works on pretty slow virtual machines(2 GHz proc + 1.75GB RAM). Working in this conditions is pretty hard, because usually build from visual studio even of 7-8 projects takes near 10 minutes. We are waiting for the new VMs but I don't expect that they will be much faster. Are there any workarounds to make a development process faster?

The only way I see now is to split one solution into several smaller solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only working on a few of the 40+ projects, unload the ones you're not using.

Right click the project in Solution Explorer -> Unload Project

You can read this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/03/06/large-visual-studio-solutions-by-loading-unloading-projects.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I enjoyed this post. Of course, I tried unloading projects and this gives a pending profit. But the projects that left a still pretty big and build of 14 projects takes about 3 minutes on a slow VM